# what is the getById() function in the deserialization function of passport.js deserialization function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

From where is this User object coming from in deserialization function it was not passed as an argument!!

Comment: I can guess it's a model from Sequelize or Mongoose